# NSPredicate crash in swift 4

Tags: ios, nspredicate, swift4

I have searching string from array of string and that code working correctly in swift 3 but after converting swift 4 i got below error when ever i start searching.

> invalid mode 'kCFRunLoopCommonModes' provided to CFRunLoopRunSpecific - break on _CFRunLoopError_RunCalledWithInvalidMode to debug. This message will only appear once per execution.
>
> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Can't do a substring operation with something that isn't a string (lhs = "A" rhs = N)'

Here is my code

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF BEGINSWITH[cd] %@", searchText)
let arrSearchData = NSMutableArray(array: arrHomeTownData.filtered(using: predicate))
```

Comment: What is data type of arrHomeTownData?

Comment: @CRDave it is NSMutableArray

Comment: NSMutableArray of what?

Comment: @CRDave NSMutableArray of string

Comment: Can you provide some part of arrHomeTownData log?

Comment: Don't use `NSMutableArray` in Swift. Never do that. You are fighting the strong type system. Most likely that causes the error: The compiler does not recognize the type. The Swift `filter` is as powerful as `NSPredicate`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got the solution , the problem was at this line

```
let arrSearchData = NSMutableArray(array: arrHomeTownData.filtered(using: predicate))
```

It became character array rather then string array so i do link this and problem solve

```
let arrSearchData : [String] = NSMutableArray(array: arrHomeTownData.filtered(using: predicate))
```